# Navigation bar transparency after push

Tags: ios, swift, transparent, navigationbar

I'm looking for a good way to make a transparent navigation bar.

With this :

```
func prepareNavigationBar(){
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.mainColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true
}
```

It work for every view, except after push. The view after push loose the transparency effect...

Have you any idea ?

Thank your

Comment: Try UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false

Comment: can you add sample snippets

Comment: `  func prepareNavigationBar(){
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.mainColor()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    }`   and `    func pushSecondView() {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSecondBookView", sender: self)
    }`

Comment: i mean to say snap shot? of both scenarios

Answer (score 0):

```
func prepareNavigationBar(){
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Try this.